# check if value already exists

Tags: c#, dictionary, contains

I have dictionary which holds my books:

```
Dictionary<string, book> books
```

Book definiton:

```
class book
{
    string author { get; set; }

    string title { get; set; }
}
```

I have added some books to the dictionary.

How can I check if there is a book in the Dictionary that matches the title provided by the user?

Comment: What value are you providing for the 'string' part of '<string,book>'?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're not using the book title as the key, then you will have to enumerate over the values and see if any books contain that title.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, book> b in books) // or foreach(book b in books.Values)
{
    if(b.Value.title.Equals("some title", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        return true
}
```

Or you can use LINQ:

```
books.Any(tr => tr.Value.title.Equals("some title", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

If, on the other hand, you are using the books title as the key, then you can simply do:

```
books.ContainsKey("some title");
```

Comment: THANK YOU, your first code helped, 
that comes to LINQ, I have never tried it before

Comment: There is .ContainsValue currently in newer version of .net framework. See @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 42):

```
books.ContainsKey("book name");
```

Comment: He want to know if it contains a book (value of dictionnary) with a known title property I think, not the dictionnary key.

Answer (score 6):

If you are allowed to use LINQ, try using the below code:

```
bool exists = books.Any(b => (b.Value != null && b.Value.title == "current title"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your dictionary, does the key hold the title? If yes, use `ContainsKey` as the other answers. If the key is something else altogether, and you want to check the value's (Book object's) `title` attribute, you'd have to do it manually like this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,book> kvp in books) {
    if (kvp.Value.title == "some title")
        return kvp.Key;
}

return String.Empty; //not found
```