# check if object already exists in Dictionary<string ,complexObject>

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop, object

I have a dictionary :

```
public Dictionary<string, ComplexType> ListUserPerFloor { get; set; }
public class ComplexType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Duration { get; set; }
    public ComplexType(string id, decimal duration)
    {
        IdUser = id;
        Duration = duration;
    }

}
public void GetUserPerFloor(TotalTimeViewModel model)
{
    var users = getUsers();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (!model.ListUserPerFloor.Any(dic => dic.Key.Contains(user.Id)))
        {
            var sum = user.Duration.GetValueOrDefault(0m);
            model.ListUserPerFloor.Add(user.Floor.ToString(), new ComplexType(user.Id, sum));
        }
        else
        {
            var sum = sc.Duration.GetValueOrDefault(0m);
            model.ListUserPerFloor[user.Floor.ToString()].Duration = model.ListUserPerFloor[user.Floor.ToString()].Duration + sum;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I check if there is a user exit in that complexe object, if user not exit , we add , else we update that object...

( the problem here :                                if (!model.ListTimeUserPerFloor.Any(dic => dic.Key.Contains(user.Id)))
i want to check if user.Id exit in the Dictionary )
example
(Floor :00,{0001,15000})
(Floor :00,{0002,16000})
...
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the definition for TotalTimeViewModel? It's not clear what's there

Comment: @umberto-petrov , thanks for ur answer , its just a simple class : (
    public class TotalTimeViewModel
{
public Dictionary<string, ComplexType> ListUserPerFloor { get; set; }
    public class ComplexType
    {
        public string IdUser { get; set; }
        public decimal Duration { get; set; }
        public ComplexType(string id, decimal duration)
        {

            IdUser = id;

            Duration = duration;
        }
   }
    }
i seems like this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436813/check-if-value-already-exists)

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve] and then improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple objects with the same key in the dictionary and the dictionary `Dictionary<string, ComplexType>` seems incorrect for string total duration.

Generally for

> How can I check if there is a user exit in that complexe object, if user not exit , we add , else we update that object...

you can use [ContainsKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=net-5.0):

```
// ContainsKey can be used to test keys before inserting
// them.
if (!openWith.ContainsKey("ht"))
{
    openWith.Add("ht", "hypertrm.exe");
    Console.WriteLine("Value added for key = \"ht\": {0}",
        openWith["ht"]);
}
```

or [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-5.0):

> ```
> // When a program often has to try keys that turn out not to
> // be in the dictionary, TryGetValue can be a more efficient
> // way to retrieve values.
> string value = "";
> if (openWith.TryGetValue("tif", out value))
> {
>    Console.WriteLine("For key = \"tif\", value = {0}.", value);
> }
> else
> {
>    Console.WriteLine("Key = \"tif\" is not found.");
> }
> ```

For your specific task I think you either want to store users per floor or only the sum of durations. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
var usersPerFloor = new Dictionary<int, List<ComplexType>>();
var users=getUsers();
foreach (var user in users)
{
    if (!usersPerFloor.ContainsKey(user.Floor))
    {
      var l = new List<ComplexType>() { new ComplexType(user.Id, user.Duration)};
      dictionary.Add(user.Floor, l);
    } 
    else 
    {
      var floorUsers = usersPerFloor[user.Floor];
      var floorUser = floorUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id);
      if(floorUser == null) 
      {
        floorUsers.Add( new ComplexType(user.Id, user.Duration));
      }
      else
      {
        floorUser.Duration += user.Duration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ListUserPerFloor.Values` to iterate though them, e.g.

```cs
if (!model.ListUserPerFloor.Values.Any(v => v.IdUser.Equals(user.id)))
{
...
}
```

Comment: `v.IdUser.Equals(user.id)` would be better as `v.IdUser == user.id` if it is possible for `v.IdUser` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to say without knowing how TotalTimeViewModel model is defined, but try something similar to this:

```
 foreach (var user in users)
 {
      if (model.ListUserPerFloor.GetType().GetProperties()
               .Select(x => x.GetValue(model.ListUserPerFloor))
               .Any(value => value.Contains(user.Id)))
      {
           // logic
      }
      else
      {
          // logic
      }
 }
```

You will likely need to modify this based on your implementation.